# Вживання post scriptum в українській мові

Tags: вживання-слів, from-latin

Питання стосується як контексту електронного листування, так і (менш формального) спілкування на форумах.

Чи є якийсь "офіційний" український відповідник до латинського `post scriptum`?

Поки схоже, що єдиного варіанту немає, а ті, що є, між собою не дуже узгоджуються:

- подекуди ([тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/38/53407/383132.html), [тут](http://pravopys.vlada.kiev.ua/kultura/shhodo-p-s-v-listi.html) і [тут](http://netiquette4uth.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/post-scriptum-ps.html)) агрументується вживання абревіатури `P.S.` латинкою;
- також інколи вживається абревіатура [`З.І.`](http://www.volkswagen.lviv.ua/threads/dlja-chajnikiv-nashogo-forumu.2290/) (набір `P.S.` кирилічною розкладкою);
- власне `post scriptum` може й просто [транслітеруватись](http://skryabin.ictv.ua/), але в одне слово;

Російською мені траплялась пара конструкцій `к слову` та `ещё к слову` у [перекладі](http://refdb.ru/look/2534473-p14.html) "Володаря Перснів" від В. С. Муравйова та  А. А. Кистяковського.

Comment: Використання З.І. - це така собі мовна гра, накшталт імітації одруків, коли палець зіскакує із клавіші Shift через емоції: "Неймовірно !!!111одинодин", але у разі "З.І." це "хотів надрукувати P.S., але забув переключити розкладку". Тобто в жартівливому листуванні можна використовувати, але не можна у офіційному листуванні.

Answer (score 8):

В неформальному електронному листуванні, коли я вже встиг відправити повідомлення, яке не маю змоги або бажання редагувати, але до змісту якого хочу щось додати (так, щоб воно логічно сприймалося частиною того ж повідомлення, незважаючи на те, що формально нею не є), я б уживав «[навздогін](http://sum.in.ua/s/navzdoghin)»

Ось декілька прикладів:

- > Пишу цей пост навздогін попередньому. //[Допис](//www.facebook.com/igor.likarchuk.9/posts/912562452180232) у Facebook.
- > Пишу навздогін оголошеному мною вчора по обіді рейтинговому, вірніше — антирейтинговому голосуванні про найбільш продажного суддю… //[Публікація «Хто був в івано-франківському суді, той в цирку не сміється»](http://versii.if.ua/publikacii/hto-buv-v-ivano-frankivskomu-sudi-toy-v-tsirku-ne-smiyetsya/) в газеті «Версії».
- > Навздогін за вчорашнім листом пишу Вам ще цих кілька слів. //[І. Ю. Мицик, Ю. А. Тарасенко «З листів Ярослава Дашкевича»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Mytsyk_Yurii/Z_lystiv_Yaroslava_Dashkevycha/), лист до Юрія Андруховича від 15 лютого 1986.
- > Пишу навздогін попередньому своєму посту. //[Допис](http://ja-mamusia.livejournal.com/201868.html) у спільноті «Я — мамуся» в LiveJournal.
- > Пишу навздогін моєму недавньому посту «Євромільйони». //[Допис](http://flaviygc.livejournal.com/615836.html) у LiveJournal.

Може скластися враження, що це дещо інше — адже ми пишемо *новий* лист навздогін попередьому, а не додаємо забуті думки *в кінці* першого листа. Але електронні засоби зв'язку стирають ці межі (час доправлення листа мізерний, найчастішою причиною не моментального отримання адресатом думок відправника є те, що сам адресат читає листи не відразу, а не термін доправлення, тому при відправленні другого листа відразу за першим висока ймовірність, що адресат прочитає їх одночасно; якщо ж перший лист ще не відправлено, то об'єктивної причини писати постскриптум і немає, бо можна просто логічно вклинити забуту інформацію у відповідні фрагменти листа, а не додавати її постскриптумом у кінці). Крім того, «навздогін» використовують і при написанні в кінці першого листа:

- > <…>
  >
  > І ще навздогін про смачне і корисне. <…>
  >
  > <sub>//[Ірена Карпа «Ле Пен, Ларусс та інші звірі – 25 „неприємних малюнків“ українки у Парижі»](//www.radiosvoboda.org/a/27635233.html) для «Радіо Свобода».</sub>
- > <…>
  >
  > P.S. Навздогін ще одна стаття Марка Ґалеотті. <…>
  >
  > <sub>//[Ярослав Грицак «Про розраду історією»](http://uamoderna.com/blogy/yaroslav-griczak/history-as-resort) для «Україна Модерна».</sub>

В останньому прикладі «P.S.» і «навздогін» фактично дублюють (чи підсилюють) одне одне. По-моєму, це необов'язково і достатньо лише одного з них:

> <…>
>
> Навздогін: <…> <sub>*— це аналог «P.S.»*</sub>
>
> І ще: <…> <sub>*— це аналог «P.P.S.»*</sub>

Що, звісно, не виключає можливості використання інших варіантів або комбінації.

Answer (score 7):

«**Постскриптум**» є словниковим словом:

- [«cловник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/postskryptum);
- [«словники України он-дайн» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BC) ([офіційний вхід сайту](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)).

Хоча лише це одне не означає, що воно є найкращим варіантом.

Answer (score 4):

Погоджуюся з відповіддю Олександра - можна вживати слово "[**Посткриптум**](http://sum.in.ua/s/postskryptum)" (також знаходимо це слово на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BC)).

А ось цей перекладач із сайту [Словенія](http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/PS/source/Fra/target/Ukr) пропонує ще й варіант "[**епілог**](http://sum.in.ua/s/epilogh)". Однак як на мене не завжди "P.s." можна замінити цим словом.

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/postskryptum) пропонує:

- **Післямова** (буде заміняти "посткриптум" у тих же випадках, що і епілог)
- Післяпис
- Заріч

У словнику синонімів бачимо слова "[**приписка**](http://sum.in.ua/s/prypyska)" ("Те, що дописане до якогось тексту, до раніш написаного") та "**[припис](http://sum.in.ua/s/prypys)**" (Те, що дописане до якогось тексту; приписка. Вона відірвала той клаптик листа, де був припис до неї, й сховала його).

Жирним шрифтом виділив ті варіанти, які мені сподобалися найбільше.